# Loop through arraylist and pass the string to custom function using EL in jsp

Tags: jsp, arraylist, el

I have written a quiet simple custom El function class which contains a method that accepts a string and returns back a string,

Here is the function :

```
public static String getOnlyName(String s) {
    String name= s.split(",")[0];
    return name;
}
```

And have declared this function in customTagLibrary.tld as follows :

```
 <function>
    <name>getSessionHere</name>
    <function-class>ohm.crm.websocket.CustomELFunction</function-class>
    <function-signature>
        java.lang.String getOnlyName(java.lang.String)
    </function-signature>
</function>
```

In JSP i am looping over the arraylist obtained from the servlet, and its working fine, but when i try to pass the looped arraylist's values i am getting :

javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression ,

and here is the way am doing it, can anybody help me out in doing it the correct way.....!!

```
<c:forEach items="${data}" var="list">
 <tr>
         <td id="${list}" name="${list}">${cg:getOnlyName(${list})}</td>                    
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem lies in calling the method "${cg:getOnlyName(${list})}"

Here is the tld file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
    <display-name>Custom EL Functions</display-name>    
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>cg</short-name>
    <uri>/WEB-INF/tld/customTagLibrary</uri>

    <function>
        <name>getSessionHere</name>
        <function-class>ohm.crm.websocket.CustomELFunction</function-class>
        <function-signature>
            java.lang.String getOnlyName(java.lang.String)
        </function-signature>
    </function> 
</taglib>
```

How is it done?

Comment: Can you show how you registered the taglib + how cg is included in your jsp page?

Comment: yep sure here it is:          <%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/customTagLibrary" prefix="cg" %>